# I am trying to use joomla.asset.json for a custom template, but I get a white page - why?

Tags: joomla-4.x, json, html

I have created a custom Joomla 4x template called 'toccata'. I have a joomla.asset.json file (shown further down below). The file is listed in my templateDetails.xml file and I thought I'd done everything right in my index.php. But, as soon as I add the following three lines, all I get is a white page. No error messages. Just nothing.

```
$wa->usePreset('template.toccata')
->useStyle('template.user')
->useScript('template.user');
```

This is my joomla.asset.json (I'm not using Bootstrap; it's a very simple site and I don't need all the code)

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
"name": "toccata",
"version": "4.0.0",
"description": "This file contains details of the assets used by Toccata, a Joomla 4 site template",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"assets": [
  {
    "name": "template.toccata",
    "description": "The main css file",
    "type": "style",
    "uri": "template.css"
  },
  {
    "name": "template.offline",
    "description": "The css file to be used when the site is offline and offline.php is being used.",
    "type": "style",
    "uri": "offline.css"
  },
  {
    "name": "template.user",
    "description": "A file where a user can add their own css.",
    "type": "style",
    "uri": "user.css",
    "dependencies": [
      "template.active"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "template.toccata",
    "description": "The file containing the javascript for this template.",
    "type": "script",
    "uri": "template.js",
    "attributes" : {
      "defer": true
    },
    "dependencies": [
      "core"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "searchtools",
    "type": "style",
    "uri": "system/searchtools/searchtools.min.css"
  }
 ]
}
```

This is the top of my index.php file:

```
<?php        
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$this->setMetaData('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;

$app = Factory::getApplication();
$wa  = $this->getWebAssetManager();

// Detecting Active Variables
$option   = $app->input->getCmd('option', '');
$view     = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');
$layout   = $app->input->getCmd('layout', '');
$task     = $app->input->getCmd('task', '');
$itemid   = $app->input->getCmd('Itemid', '');
$sitename = htmlspecialchars($app->get('sitename'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$menu     = $app->getMenu()->getActive();
$pageclass = $menu !== null ? 
$menu->getParams()->get('pageclass_sfx', '') : '';
// Template path
$templatePath = 'templates/' . $this->template;

$wa->usePreset('template.toccata')
    ->useStyle('template.user')
    ->useScript('template.user');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="metas" />
    <jdoc:include type="styles" />
    <jdoc:include type="scripts" />
</head>
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is it because I'm not using template.min.css but only template.css?

Note: if I include links to the CSS in the head of the document and the template.js at the bottom, deferred, it displays fine.

Comment: The first thing I can spot is that you use `usePreset()` method in your `index.php` but there is no `type: preset` defined in your `joomla.asset.json` file. So you should add a `"name": "template.toccata", "type": "preset"...` entry in your json file with adding the dependencies of that preset too. You can check the core cassiopeia template json file as an example for that. Then you should be able to use `usePreset()`. At least, this is what I see at first glance.

Comment: This missing entry for sure can cause internal server error.

Comment: Thanks. I'd originally used ```useStyle``` but when that didn't work I tried ```usePreset``` after Googling for solutions, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: I see. However `useStyle()`, even if the path to css for example is not defined well in the json file, will not cause server error.

Comment: You mentioned in your question that something in these three lines are causing the “blank page”(server error), so we do not have too many choices here.

Comment: is the Debug system On? is the Error reporting on maximum? This asset manager has quite good error catching system.